# VBA Macro to report links on powerpoint slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to modify some code to retrieve any links in powerpoint slides and print them to a document. I am struggling to get the objects.

Here is what I have already:

```
Sub LinkCounter()
    Dim FileNum As Integer
    Dim oFile As String
    Dim textLink() As Shape, i As Long
    
    
    FileNum = FreeFile()
    oFile = ActivePresentation.Path & "\LinksReport.txt"
    If Dir(oFile, vbNormal) <> vbNullString Then
        Kill oFile
    End If


i = 0
p = 1

Open oFile For Append As #FileNum
    Print #FileNum, "Links counted on slides"
For Each Slide In ActivePresentation.Slides
Print #FileNum, "Slide"; p
p = p + 1

    For Each Hyperlinks.Address In Slide.Hyperlinks

               Set textLink(i) = Hyperlinks.Address
               Print #FileNum, textLink(i)
               i = i + 1
Next Hyperlinks.Address

Next Slide


Close FileNum

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After some deeper searching I found a piece of code that achieves this, it would be good to know where I went wrong however, I'm guessing I need to loop through shapes to find the links?

```
Sub PPHyperlinkReport()
Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oHl As Hyperlink
Dim sReport As String
Dim iFileNum As Integer
Dim sFileName As String
For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
For Each oHl In oSl.Hyperlinks
If oHl.Type = msoHyperlinkShape Then
If oHl.Address <> "" Then
sReport = sReport & "HYPERLINK IN SHAPE" _
& vbCrLf _
& "Slide: " & vbTab & oSl.SlideIndex _
& vbCrLf _
& "Shape: " & vbTab & oHl.Parent.Parent.Name _
& vbCrLf _
& "Text: """ & oHl.Parent.Parent.TextFrame.TextRange.Text & """" _
& vbCrLf _
& "External link address:" & vbTab & oHl.Address & vbCrLf & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

Else
sReport = sReport & ""
End If

Else
If oHl.Address <> "" Then
sReport = sReport & "HYPERLINK IN TEXT" _
& vbCrLf _
& "Slide: " & vbTab & oSl.SlideIndex _
& vbCrLf _
& "Shape: " & vbTab & oHl.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Name _
& vbCrLf _
& "Text: """ & oHl.Parent.Parent.Text & """" _
& vbCrLf _
& "External link address:" & vbTab & oHl.Address & vbCrLf & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

Else
sReport = sReport & ""
End If
End If
Next ' hyperlink
Next ' Slide
iFileNum = FreeFile()
sFileName = ActivePresentation.Path & "\AuthorTec_Edits.txt"
Open sFileName For Output As iFileNum
Print #iFileNum, sReport
Close #iFileNum
Call Shell("NOTEPAD.EXE " & sFileName, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Comment: Mainly, your original code is trying to loop through each Hyperlinks.Address In Slide.Hyperlinks, but there's no Hyperlinks.Address collection.  Hyperlinks is the collection, .Address is a property of a single Hyperlink. The code you found (likely on https://www.pptfaq.com, where I posted it, you're welcome!) loops through the .Hyperlinks collection of each slide and looks at the .Address of each.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! and code I guess! The structure of the objects is killing me!

Comment: Like any unfamiliar app, the object model takes a bit of getting used to. Shove me into the middle of Word and I'm totally lost. But if you set the IDE to always include Option Explicit and compile before running your code, it'll save you a lot of hassle. Intellisense and the object browser (hit F2 in the IDE) are your buddies. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need, but with links embedded on images. Here's the macro, tested on macOS with VBA 7.1 :

```
Sub ExtractImageHyperlinks()
Dim ppt As Presentation
Dim slide As slide
Dim shape As shape
Dim txtFile As String
Dim linkText As String

txtFile = "/Users/XXXX/Desktop/ImageHyperlinks.txt"

Open txtFile For Output As #1
Set ppt = ActivePresentation

For Each slide In ppt.Slides
    For Each shape In slide.Shapes
        If shape.Type = msoPicture Then
            Dim actionSetting As actionSetting
            Set actionSetting = shape.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)
            If Not actionSetting Is Nothing Then
                If actionSetting.Action = ppActionHyperlink Then
                    linkText = actionSetting.Hyperlink.Address
                    Print #1, linkText
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next shape
Next slide

Close #1
MsgBox "Hyperlinks from images have been extracted and saved to " & txtFile, vbInformation
End Sub
```